# zftool not behaving as expected

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I have a hosting service in linux, where I’m trying to develop an app on zend framework 2.  I want to use zftool but regardless which zftool command I run, I get always the HTML of the home page.

I’ll really appreciate any help.

---

Here are the steps to reproduce:

1 - I installed composer

```
>curl -s https://getcomposer.org/installer | php
```

2 - I installed the Skeleton MVC application

```
>php composer.phar create-project -sdev --repository-url="https://packages.zendframework.com" zendframework/skeleton-application ./hmzf
```

3 - Brought Composer up to date

```
>php composer.phar self-update
```

4 - Install ZFTool

```
>php composer.phar require zendframework/zftool:dev-master
```

5 - Createa symbolic link to invoke it from my project directory

```
>ln -s ./vendor/zendframework/zftool/zf.php zf.php
```

6 - Run zf.php to get the list of modules and what I get in return is the html of the home page of the skeleton app:

```
> php zf.php modules
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue.  I had to use php-cli to invoke zf.php.  So instead of issuing:

> php zf.php modules

which will echo the zend app home page HTML to the console, I had to issue:

> php5.4-cli zf.php modules

and I've got the right response from the tool, which is:

Modules installed:
Application