# zf.php won't recognize any command

Tags: zend-framework2, zftool2

I'm using the ZF2 Skeleton application. I installed zftool using composer: `composer require zendframework/zftool:dev-master` but then, when I run `zf.php` I get the HTML of the Skeleton app homepage instead of a list of commands or something...

Any ideas? Thanks!

Edit:

This is the output from `php-v`:

```
PHP 5.6.23-2+deb.sury.org~trusty+1 (cli) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2016 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.6.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2016 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.0.6-dev, Copyright (c) 1999-2016, by Zend Technologies
```

Comment: Just found this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28056735/zftool-not-behaving-as-expected which seemed like a good hint, but didn't work... I don't have a specific php-cli file to execute...

Comment: zf.php must be run from console. For Windows, like ``php vendor\zendframework\zftool\zf.php modules list``

Comment: You should check that the php executable you are using is the one you're expecting. Run `which php` to find out what your include path is returning for php. What OS are you running on?

Comment: I'm on LinuxMint 17